# Xcode ios build failed from after update in xcode 14.0

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, flutter-ios-build

I am using mac (with m1 chip) and trying to generate Flutter app ios build from Xcode.
It was required to update the Xcode to version 14.0, I updated that and got so many errors like in the screenshot.
I tried a lot like re-installation of pod folder, and other more tricks to resolve these issues but unable to find out the right solution. [image]

Comment: It looks like you might need a new version of `shared_preferences_ios`